# Continuos integration support in LUIS and QNA Maker

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am looking  for Continuous integration (Version control support) from LUIS and QNA Maker which helps me in Staging environment Eg: Moving my code from development to production environment. Do you have any feature like this currently? If not is there any roadmap for the same?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand what specifically you're asking for in the context of these two services. That said, for LUIS there exist [app versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions), and two "types" of slots for publishing; [`staging` and `production`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp#publish-your-trained-app-to-an-http-endpoint).

For QnA Maker it doesn't look like this exists; to request it to be added as a feature, you can visit the [UserVoice for QnA Maker](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/578689-qna-maker-api) and submit a request there.